# How to prove the my greedy algorithm for placing guards?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, greedy-algorithms

> Given $n$ images placed in indexes $x_1 < x_2 < ... < x_n$ and an endless number of guards, where each guard if placed in index $y$ can protect $[y-0.5,y+1]$. I want to protect all images with **minimum** possible number of guards.

My suggestion for an algorithm:

Place a guard at $x_1+0.5$ then loop from $i=2$ to $i=n$, if image $x_i$ is protected by the previous guard then do nothing, else place a new guard at point $x_i+0.5.$

---

I proved that my algorithm returns a valid solution, but am stuck on proving that it returns the minimum solution.

I am trying to prove this claim:

*Let $s_i$ be the number of guards placed until and including the point $x_i + 0.5$ Then for each i there is an optimal solution which used exactly $s_i$ guards until and including the point $x_i + 0.5.$*

I proved this in 3 pages in case the algorithm adds new guard in step $k$, and only now I discovered a HUGE problem in the induction.
what if in step $k$ my algorithm didn't add a new guard?

How can I still prove that the optimal solution which is guaranteed for $k-1$ is still valid (I think in some cases it's not and we need to make some changes to it by moving some or all guards...)?

Comment: Do you mean that the $n$ images are placed on a line?

Comment: @phan801 yes I do

Comment: Are you sure, you want to prove "minimal" and not "minimum"?

Comment: Updated thanks for your note :)

Comment: Please don't use "Update:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/271/755.

Comment: I'm having a hard time identifying what your specific question is.  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to formulate an explicit question.  A question normally ends in "?".  I suggest [edit]ing your question to make it clearer.  I'm not sure what "still prove that the optimal solution which is guaranteed for k−1 is still valid" means.

Comment: "what if in step k my algorithm didn't add a new guard?" @D.W.

Comment: I can't tell what kind of answer you are looking for.  I'm not sure how we're supposed  to answer "What if?"  Also that doesn't sound like a question for us to answer; it sounds like you identifying a flaw in your proof.  I suggest spending some more time on identifying what the question you want answered is, and then organizing your post so that comes across clearly with no possibility of confusion.  The easier you make it for readers to understand what you are asking, the more likely that you get a useful answer.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I guess the induction hypothesis should be that all pictures up to and including $x_{k-1}$ are protected with a minimum number of guards (no matter whether in the last step you added one or not). Then you will have to prove whether the pictures up to and including $x_{k}$ are also protected in an optimal way, by adding or not adding a guard. So, the induction is not over the guards that you add, but over the index $i$ that you use.

Comment: @coolmo If you insist on mathematical induction, here is the right proposition to prove: for any $m$ guards that cover the images at $x_{s_1}, x_{s_2},\cdots, x_{s_m}$, the rightmost point they can cover is $x_{s_m}+1.5$. Here $x_1\text{=}x_{s_1}, x_{s_2},x_{s_3},\cdots,$ are the location of the images selected by your greedy algorithm.

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple reasoning that shows your greedy algorithm is correct. No mathematical induction is required.

Call an image critical if the greedy algorithm places a guard $0.5$ after it.

The algorithm ensures that each critical image is more than $1.5$ away from the previous critical image (except the first image, before which there is no image). That means any two critical images are more than $1.5$ apart.

Since a guard covers an interval of length $1.5$, it can cover at most one critical image. So, any solution must place at least as many guards as critical images. The greedy algorithm places exactly one guard for each critical image. So, the greedy algorithm is optimal.$\quad\checkmark$